# Wordpress add template not loading templates

Tags: wordpress, elementor

New to wordpress when trying to add template in Elementor it is loading but doest not show any templates.
Please help how to solve this issue image below not loading.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot load templates, what can I do?

Go to Elementor > System Info, and check whether  Elementor's  Library is connected or not.
Go to Elementor > Tools and synchronize the library.

Click on "sync library" in the "tools" tab of Elementor in your WordPress dashboard if it is not synced

Answer (score -2):

It's because of your addblock. Try to disable it or use another browser.

Comment: I am curious, how do you know that the person is using adblock? Could you elaborate a little further your question? Thanks.